# How to add a custom attribute to a CMS message with Apple CMS services?

Tags: macos, cryptography, asn.1, pkcs#7, pades

We would like to add an additional OID tag to the CMS signer info sequence using the [Cryptographic Message Syntax Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/cryptographic_message_syntax_services?language=objc) library in macOS. We are able to generate a CMS message using the provided `CMSEncoder*` functions but are unable to insert the signing-certificate OID tag (1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.12) needed for conformance with the [CAdES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAdES_(computing)) standard. Is there a way to insert a custom attribute into the signer sequence of a CMS message generated with [Apple's CMS Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/cryptographic_message_syntax_services?language=objc) library?